# Fitnesse usage of method with multiple arguments

Tags: java, fitnesse

maybe you know how can I override the problem I got..
So in my Java code, I have a method like

```
createMacTrackEventParam(int hcuId, int portId, int perfIndex, int ...chanInd)
```

as you see, I expect that I can use many chanInd (I can use none, and I can use 1, 5, 10 etc. etc.)
I also put this method in wsdd file and put `<ns1:parameter qname="ns99:chanInd" type="xsd:int" />`
which might be incorrect, but I don't actually know.

So, I am trying to use the method in Fitnesse like

```
|createMacTrackEventParam|$HCU_UID  ||$PORT_UID  ||75  || *** |
```

where if I put nothing instead of ** I receive "CANT_CONVERT_TO_INTEGER_LIST" error, and if I put anything like "1", or "1, 75" or "20, 30, 40" I receive "argument type mismatch" exception.

What can I do to make this method work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like variadic arguments are not supported.  Try using an array instead: int[] chanInd with a comma-separated list in the FitNesse cell.